# Go function parameters

Tags: go

```
func (db *Database) VerifyEmail(emailAddress string) (*data.UserName, error) {
....
}
```

Can someone please help clarify 1.what and 2.why with the above function? From the [docs](https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/) and [this](https://gobyexample.com/functions) book I can tell that VerifyEmail is taking in emailAdress as a parameter and returning what I think is the  memory address to a username.

However, what does `(db *Database)` do? I mean why put that after `func` and before the name of the function? And what may be some reasons to pass the memory address to a function as a pointer as opposed to the variable representing it?

Comment: It's the method receiver (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations), similar to other languages' "this", and you use a pointer if the object may be large or the method may need to change the object--if you copy the thing, the method can only change *its copy* of the object.

Comment: @twotwotwo can you please paste this in answer so I can accept it? Thank you! Makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(*db Database)` in front of the method name is the [method receiver](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations), similar to other languages' "this", and you use a pointer if the object may be large or the method may need to change the object--if you copy it, the method can only change its copy of the object.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, you can define methods using both pointer and no-pointer method [receivers](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets). The formate feels like `func (t *Type)` and `func (t Type)` respective.

So what’s the difference between pointer and non-pointer method receivers?

a) Reasons when use pointer receiver?

1. You want to actually modify the receiver (`read/write` as opposed to just “read”)
2. The struct is very large and a deep copy is expensive.
3. Consistency: if some of the methods on the struct have pointer receivers, the rest should too. This allows predictability of behavior.
4. If the receiver is a large struct or array, a pointer receiver is more efficient.

If you need these characteristics on your method call, use a pointer receiver.

b) Reasons when use value receiver?

1. If the receiver is a map, func or chan, don't use a pointer to it.
2. If the receiver is a slice and the method doesn't reslice or reallocate the slice, don't use a pointer to it.